# Preview email generated by Microsoft Outlook Object Library

Tags: c++, email, outlook

Is it possible to preview the email generated by Microsoft Outlook Object Library?

I currently construct a MailItem, fill it with relevant information then send it. I would like to have Outlook open and preview the email and allow the user to send the email rather than having it automatically sent.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Instead of calling `MailItem.Send`, call `MailItem.Display`.

Comment: I thought that would work, but I am not sure what to pass for the param VARIANT &Modal.

Comment: Variant of type VT_BOOLEAN

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry.